# Why does setattr does not work as a method?

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

I want to change some attributes of a class programmtically.

I found, that there's the `setattr`-function, but it does not work as exptected.

```
> obj.setattr('bar', 99)
'MyClass' object has no attribute 'setattr'
```

Instead, I have to use

```
> setattr(obj, 'bar', 99)
```

Why is this? I thought, in python the call of a method by an object sets the object itself as the first parameter and so both should mean the same.

Or does `Object` simply not has the definition of `setattr`?

Comment: Special methods have `__` around them: `obj.__setattr__`.

Comment: `setattr` is a function, not a method, that's it.

Comment: A call of a `method` binds the object the method refers to as first parameter to the function. But `setattr` is a plain `function` - not a method.

Comment: A method call invocation does automatically insert self, but the method must still exist. A `setattr` method doesn't exist, a global function of that babe does. You can call `__setattr__`, the method called by the global `setattr` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `object` setattr method is `__setattr__`:

```
>>> dir(object)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```

And `__setattr__('y', v)` will be called when you use `x.y = v`.

The help info of `setattr`:

```
setattr(x, 'y', v) is equivalent to ``x.y = v''.
```

So `setattr(x, 'y', v)` is equivalent to `x.y = v` and then equivalent to `x.__setattr__('y', v)`

Comment: But be aware that `__setattr__` is supposed to be used by internal things and might act different than wanted, or might even not exist. Better use the builtin function `setattr()` instead.